# Add National Hydrography Dataset basemap to leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, gis

I'd like to add the NHD (National Hydrography Dataset) basemap (tile) to my leaflet map. [Here](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/help/3.0%20TNM%20Base%20Maps.htm) is link that provides the Hydrography url I'm trying to use.

```
leaflet()%>%
  setView(lng = -76.4, lat = 37, zoom = 09) %>% 
  addWMSTiles(baseUrl="https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSHydroCached/MapServer",
              layers="Hydrography")
```

The basemap currently returned is completely blank. I expect it to look like [this](https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/example/maps/Leaflet_Example.html) Adding WMS tiles from other sources seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1 Follow [this](https://owi.usgs.gov/blog/basemaps/) tutorial by USGS.

`grp <- c("USGS Topo", "USGS Imagery Only", 
 "USGS Imagery Topo","USGS Shaded Relief", "Hydrography")`

```
GetURL <- function(service, host = "basemap.nationalmap.gov") {
sprintf("https://%s/arcgis/services/%s/MapServer/WmsServer", host, 
service)}`

opt <- leaflet::WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE)

map <- leaflet::leaflet()
map <- leaflet::addWMSTiles(map, GetURL("USGSHydroCached"),
   group = grp[5], options = opt, layers = "0")

map <- leaflet::hideGroup(map, grp[5])`
```

Option #2 Using `inlmisc` package, the `CreateWebMap` function adds a hydrography baselayer by default